# What's wrong with my Euclidean Distance Calculation? (Julia)

Tags: julia, distance, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to compute the Perceptually Important Points by using three different methods.

1. Euclidean Distance;
2. Perpendicular Distance;
3. Vertical Distance.

Method 2 and 3 gives me the same Point, but Euclidean distance not. Can't find the mistake I made. Hope someone can help me.

```
pt = 7.6 #pt
_t = 1 #t
ptT = 10.7 #p(t+T)
_T = 253 #t+T

# Distances
dE = Float64[] #Euclidean Distances
dP = Float64[] #Perpendicular Distances
dV = Float64[] #Vertical Distances
xi = Float64[] #x values

for i in 2:length(stockdf[:Price])-1
_de = sqrt((_t - i)^2 + (pt - stockdf[:Price][i])^2) + sqrt((_T - i)^2 + (ptT - stockdf[:Price][i])^2)
push!(dE,_de)

_dP = abs(_s*i+_c-stockdf[:Price][i])/sqrt(_s^2+1)
push!(dP,_dP)

_dV = abs(_s*i+_c-stockdf[:Price][i])
push!(dV,_dV)

push!(xi,i)
end
```

Both method 2 and 3 give me the max point indexed at 153, but method 1 gives me a point, which is not the max point and is indexed at 230.

Formula for the 3rd PIP with Euclidean Distance is:

```
dE = sqrt((t-i)^2 + (pt-pi)^2) + sqrt((t+T-i)^2+(pt+T-pi)^2)
```

**EDIT:**
For a better understanding I reproduced the code with other variables which you can test for yourself.

```
xs = Array(1:10)
ys = rand(1:1:10,10)

dde = Float64[]
ddP = Float64[]
ddV = Float64[]
xxi = Float64[]

# Connecting Line of first 2 PIPs
_ss = (ys[end]-ys[1])/10
_cc = ys[1]-(1*(ys[end]-ys[1]))/10
_zz = Float64[]

for i in 1:length(dedf[:Price])
    push!(_zz,_ss*i+_cc)
end


for i in 2:length(xs)-1
    _dde = sqrt((1-i)^2+(ys[1]-ys[i])) + sqrt((10-i)^2 + (ys[end]-    ys[i])^2)
    push!(dde,_dde)

    _ddP = abs(_ss*i+_cc-ys[i])/sqrt(_ss^2+1)
    push!(ddP,_ddP)

    _ddV = abs(_ss*i+_cc-ys[i])
    push!(ddV,_ddV)

    push!(xxi,i)
end
println(dde)

for i in 1:length(dde)
    if ddV[i] == maximum(ddV)
        println(i)
    end
end
```

For Euclidean Distance I get index 7 
for Perpendicular and Vertical Distance I get index 5. Look at the graphs
[Euclidean Distance on graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE0Z5.png)

[Perpendicular Distance on graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX0bf.png)

**EDIT:**
I'm working through a book about pattern recognition in financial time series. Now I downloaded the same data, which the book used and the now the results are the same. All of the 3 methods gave me the same index. But with different data sets, method 1 differs from 2 and 3. I don't know why.

Comment: Different metrics in general give different results. Why do you think there is a bug?

Comment: I'm working through the book "Technical Analysis for Algorithmic Pattern Recognition by Tsinaslanidis & Zapranis" and they got identical results with all the methods. But in my case I get 2 different results. That's what's confusing me.

Comment: The calculation of `_ss` may be off. The slope should equal the last minus the first point divided by the distance between them. In the code it is `10` but there are only **9** intervals between 10 points.

Comment: @DanGetz The slope is fine (look at the pictures above). I guess it's something with the data. Maybe the correct points will be calculated as as the number of points increases. As I mentioned above in the last Edit, with the data used in the book, there are no problems in the calculation. Different answers only occur when I use different data. Then methods 2&3 give me a different result than the Euclidean Distance calculation does. But thanks for your answer Dan.

Comment: The code you added to the question does not run when pasted (there are a couple of problems - `dedf` undefined and a missing `^2` in Euclidean distance). As for the question, the three metrics are different and in general should not achieve a maximum at the same points.

Comment: The vertical and perpendicular distances achieve the maximum at the same point (they are proportional to each other). The Euclidean distance is different and often achieves maximum at same point but does not have to.

Comment: @DanGetz I understand. Thank you very much.